# GraphView not refreshing unless view is touched?

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I'm working with [jjoe64's GraphView project](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) but I am having issues when adding data on the fly. I'm trying to plot microphone volumes on a line graph but the graph refuses to update. Here's what I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.GraphLayout);

    graph = new LineGraphView(this, "Sounds");
    data = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphView.GraphViewData[] { new GraphView.GraphViewData(X++, 0) });
    graph.addSeries(data);
    graph.setManualYAxis(true);
    graph.setManualYAxisBounds(32767, 0);
    graph.setViewPort(3, 100);
    graph.setScrollable(true);
    layout.addView(graph);

    final MediaRecorder media = new MediaRecorder();
    media.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    media.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    media.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    media.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
    try {
        media.prepare();
    } catch (Throwable t) {}
    media.start();

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final int amp = media.getMaxAmplitude();
            MaxSoFar = Math.max(amp, MaxSoFar);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    data.appendData(new GraphView.GraphViewData(X++, amp), true);
                    //Here I try few different things
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
                    String info = MaxSoFar + "" + nl;
                    info += amp + "";
                    output.setText(info);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 100);
}
```

I've been doing a lot of experimenting on the line immediately after `data.appendData(...)` with things like `graph.redrawAll();`, `graph.invalidate();`, or `graph.postInvalidate();` but nothing. I can only get the graph to redraw if I put my finger down and drag the graph. Any sort of touch input will cause the graph to draw correctly. It might have something to do with it being in `runOnUiThread` but I can't think why that might be an issue and not a requirement.

I'm debugging this on my Galaxy S3 running Cyanogenmod 10.1 Nightlies (Android 4.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little research and experimenting, I found that there's [this issue](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/39) where Lauszus said he had [this fix](https://github.com/Lauszus/GraphView/commit/6c9fa1c6317f3c2dc93c5edf0847a242c65dc2df). I made those changes and rebuilt GraphView and it works wonderfully.